# PCA in GEE, layer error mesage-Computation time out

Tags: google-earth-engine, pca

I am trying to get the PCA using following codes for sentinel 2A in GEE, but I get the message-computation time out. Is there a way to solve the issue?

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2022-1-01', '2023-01-30')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5)) 
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var s2a=dataset.median().clip(nepal);

var bands=['B2','B3','B4','B5','B8','B11'];

var arrayImage = s2a.select(bands).toArray();

var covar = arrayImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.covariance(),
  geometry:nepal,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
  scale:10,
  bestEffort: true

  });

var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);

var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors)
.matrixMultiply(arrayImage.toArray(1));


var pcImage = principalComponents
    .arrayProject([0])
   .arrayFlatten([['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc5', 'pc6']]);

var pc1=pcImage.select('pc1');
print(pc1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scale issue. So, by using an arbitrary area in Nepal (you don't provide one) as your roi and modifying following variable as follows:

```
var covar = arrayImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.covariance(),
  geometry:nepal,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
  scale:100,
  bestEffort: true

  });
```

your [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cbaa30a6ba73c69ec28cdf3a2cdf2141) woks without any problem; as it can be observed in following picture:

[image]

Comment: For small area, it is fine, but for larger area like whole Nepal, same problem still exists using scale of 100. Shouldn't be scale the resolution of the sentinel image, rather than any other values.

Comment: Myself, I've never got that `reduceRegion()` in PCA to work at smaller scales for larger areas. You can get it working for a bit bigger areas by exporting the image, and perhaps setting `tileScale` to `16`. But that too fails at some point.